# Was there a change in the npm default location for coffee-script?

Tags: coffeescript

I found I was running an old version of coffeescript.

So I decided to reinstall it:

```
npm install -g coffee-script
```

But it did not seem to update coffee.

I noticed that npm installed coffee here:

```
usr/local/share/npm/bin/coffee -> 
    /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee
```

But my the coffee in my path is

```
/usr/local/bin/coffee -> 
    ../lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee
```

AFAIK, I used npm to originally install coffeescript (months ago).
But now npm is putting it in a completely new path.

Was there a change for the default location of coffeescript when installed by
via npm on Mac OS X?

Comment: Just installed coffescript on a new machine and I get it on usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffeescript. It seems it changed the path because it was installed as share for other machines/accounts (note the path usr/local/share)